# fragment reloading after exiting the activity in android

Tags: java, android

I have been working on an application where i have a fragment which communicates with an activity.
In that communication i have applied shared element transition and so far it works however the problem arises when i exit the activity and return to fragment after two seconds the fragments starts reloading i tried searching for a possible solution but couldnt find the reason for that so i was hoping if someone could help me out here.

**Update: As i Have used shared element transition for animation and i noticed that without transition on back press the fragment isn't recreated and it works fine however with animation it is recreated again after few seconds.**
Here is my fragment code

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed, container, false);
        getActivity().getWindow().setExitTransition(null);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        toolbar = (Toolbar)view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        // ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        feed_recycler_view = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.feed_recycler_view);
        //ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(feed_recycler_view, false  );
        CustomTextView customTextView = (CustomTextView)toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);


        feed_layout_manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
        feed_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(feed_layout_manager);
        //feed_recycler_view.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        feed_recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true);
        feed_adapter = new FeedAdapter(FeedUtils.generateFeeds(getContext()),this);
        feed_recycler_view.setAdapter(feed_adapter);
        return view;
    }

    public static FeedFragment newInstance() {
        FeedFragment fragment = new FeedFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    public static void applyFont(CustomTextView tv, Activity context) {
        tv.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Quicksand-Medium.ttf"));
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onBackPressed() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFeedItemClick(int pos, Feed_Data_Provider feedDataProvider, AppCompatImageView shareImageView) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), ChatActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_FEED_ITEM, feedDataProvider);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_FEED_IMAGE_TRANSITION_NAME, ViewCompat.getTransitionName(shareImageView));

        ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
                getActivity(),
                shareImageView,
                ViewCompat.getTransitionName(shareImageView));

        startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
    }
}
```

And here is the activity class

```
public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        AppCompatImageView chat_image;
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
        getWindow().setEnterTransition(null);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        Feed_Data_Provider feedItem = extras.getParcelable(FeedFragment.EXTRA_FEED_ITEM);
        chat_image = (AppCompatImageView)findViewById(R.id.chat_image);
        postponeEnterTransition();
        int imageUrl =feedItem.getClub_image();
        supportPostponeEnterTransition();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            String imageTransitionName = extras.getString(FeedFragment.EXTRA_FEED_IMAGE_TRANSITION_NAME);
            if (imageTransitionName != null) {
                chat_image.setTransitionName(imageTransitionName);
            }
        }
        Glide.with(this)
                .load(imageUrl)
                .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        supportStartPostponedEnterTransition();
                        return false;

                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        supportStartPostponedEnterTransition();
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .into(chat_image);

    }


}
```

Comment: ChatActivity itself contains FeedFragment. So if you exit your Activity it will be destroyed and the fragment which is a part of Activity, it will be destroyed too. So when you start activity again, it will again initialize fragment, so the reloading happens everytime.

Comment: So how do i stop that from happening please tell me

Comment: @PragneshGhodaシ could you please help me how i can solve this issue

Comment: what is your flow ? If you destroy activity, the containing fragment will be destroyed too. if you want to update data of fragment, you need to update fragment while activity is alive.

Comment: actually i have main activity acting as a container for other fragments and when i click data in one fragment it opens detail activity and i have very less knowledge of working with fragments

Comment: @PragneshGhodaシ how could i resolve the problem